# Does Google nearby message API needs Internet connection to work?

Tags: google-api, p2p, google-nearby

Hi I want to create an app using google nearby message api. I want it to be completely offline.
Is it possible? Does google needs internet connection for using this Nearby api?
I know it uses bluetooth and WIFI things to share the data! 
I want to know whether it needs internet connection at its initial stage? since it needs to retrieve some token from the cloud.

Help me in this!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Nearby Messages requires devices to have internet access.  Discovery is accomplished via BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy), WiFi, and audio (using near-ultrasonic frequencies), but the cloud is needed for message delivery after discovery.  Nearby doesn't yet provide a pure peer-to-peer solution.

Comment: Okay For cloud initialization we need internet connection right!

Comment: @Dan Webb approximately how long is the distance for DISTANCE_TYPE_DEFAULT ?

Comment: On Android devices that support Bluetooth 4.0 (which is most of them nowadays), Nearby will use Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) to discover nearby devices.  BLE has a range of up to ~100m outdoors, but the indoor range is much lower due to obstacles.  In a typical indoor environment, the range should be at least 10m.